# Need an egrep Regular Express to Exclude A Word

Tags: regex, grep, regex-negation

**REQUIREMENT**:

I am trying to create 2 regular expressions for egrep:

1. To scan Oracle DDL scripts to identify files that create PACKAGE bodies
2. To scan Oracle DDL scripts to identify files that create PACKAGE specifications

The syntax used in the DDL script files is:

`CREATE [OR REPLACE] PACKAGE [BODY] <name> AS`

The optional keyword "BODY" indicates a body. If it is missing, the script is assumed to create a package spec.

Consider these 4 test files (named f1, f2, f3, and f4):

f1:

`CREATE    OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package as`

f2:

`CREATE    OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_package as`

f3:

`CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE   BODY my_package AS`

f4:

`CREATE  PACKAGE body my_package AS`

**NOTE** that f3 contains multiple spaces between "PACKAGE" and "BODY"

**PROBLEM**

I have a good working expression to identify the package body scripts:

`egrep -il 'CREATE[ ]+(OR[ ]+REPLACE[ ]+)?PACKAGE[ ]+BODY'`

Now I need one to scan for the specification scripts (the ones that don't have the word "BODY" after the word "PACKAGE". I assume it would be the same expression with some syntax that says "the word PACKAGE is not followed by the word BODY".

I tried this:

`egrep -il 'CREATE[ ]+(OR[ ]+REPLACE[ ]+)?PACKAGE[ ]+[^(BODY)]' f*`

The command above finds f1, f2, and f3. For some reason, it works correctly where there is only one space between "PACKAGE" and "BODY" but not where there is more than one.

Thanks for you consideration of my problem.

-Scott K.

Comment: You could probably spare yourself the headache of trying to create a regex to match the non-existence of something by simply switching the logic from "select lines that match ..." to "select lines that don't match ...". In this case `egrep -v -il BODY ...`. Possibly then piped into (or from) your positive match `egrep -il 'CREATE.....'`.

Comment: twalberg, I agree. That is plan b. I would like to do something more elegant and learn something about regex in the process. Appreciate your input.